# Register Action Does Not Redirect to Login Page After Uploading File With Extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am extending asp.net MVC's register action. When the user clicks register, the action uploads the users photograph and persists their data to the database, after which it is expected to redirect the user to the login page.
The problem now is that it does not redirect the user to the login page on successful registration, rather it completes the registration and keeps them on the register page.
But if I upload the file without the extension, the user gets redirected as expected.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase passportUpload)
{            
    //Some code here

    if (ModelState.IsValid && passportUpload != null)
    {
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(passportUpload.FileName);

        var fileNameWithExtension = Path.GetFileName(passportUpload.FileName);
        var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(passportUpload.FileName);

        string image = "/images/profile/" + model.Email +"/"+ fileNameWithExtension;
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/profile"), model.Email);

        string imageUrl = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/profile/" + model.Email), fileNameWithExtension);

        var directory = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        model.passportUpload.SaveAs(imageUrl);                

        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            CategoryId = category.Id,
            UserName = model.Email,
            Email = model.Email,
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            OtherName = model.OtherName,
            LastName = model.LastName,
            Gender = model.Gender,
            PassportUrl = image,                            
        };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //Comment line below to disable auto sign in after registration
            //await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            var currentUser = UserManager.FindById(user.Id);

            var roleResult = UserManager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id, "Client User");

            return RedirectToAction("Account", "Login");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

When the user clicks submit, the data gets persisted to the database as expected but when after RedirectToAction("Account", "Login"); gets read the controller tranfers execution to this block of code:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        if (_userManager != null)
        {
            _userManager.Dispose();
            _userManager = null;
        }

        if (_signInManager != null)
        {
            _signInManager.Dispose();
            _signInManager = null;
        }
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

If I update the code to upload a file without an extension, it redirects to the login page as expected.
Is there a reason why the code works differently when uploading a file with an extension and when we upload a file without one?
And is there a way around this?
Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that the `passportUpload` variable should more correctly be in the model. If the file/filename is being put into the URL, you're going to end up with issues. Having a `PassportUpload` property on `RegisterViewModel` should solve your issue

Comment: @mjwills Sorry, should have been clearer. Extension in this case is .jpg, .png etc.

Comment: @mjwills When I step through the code, it gets to the return RedirectToAction("Account", "Login"); line passes it then calls the  Dispose method. A value that worked was 'face', a value that didn't work is 'face.jpg'.

Comment: What is the value of `image` when it succeeds, and when it fails? How is the `PassportUrl` column defined in the database (column type and size)?